Screen flickering in 24.04
My laptop is a purpose built Linux laptop from the company Tuxedo Computers. It has served me well through several Ubuntu upgrades over the seven of so years since I bought it. Since upgrading to 24.04 from 23.10 the screen flickers for a few seconds every so often, it is not nice. I never noticed this before upgrading but now it happens a lot. Moving the mouse seems to stop it for a while. Of course the problem could be an hardware issue as the laptop is getting old but is does seem strange that it started with the 24.04 upgrade.
Has anyone else had this problem or knows how the fix it?
By the way I have used Wayland since 22.04 so I don't think Wayland is the problem.

For problems like this, you better add system information, in particular graphics card. Use "edit"  to add the information to your question.
